# generate random number and fill them in array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to generate 10 random number between 1 and 100 and store them in an array

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<10; i++))
do

done
```

Comment: A shotcut: `arr=( $(seq 1 20 | shuf | head -n 10) )`

Comment: can you update the question with what you mean by `'not similar'`? do you mean `no duplicates`? something else?

Comment: Please do not fundamentally change your question when an answer has already been given.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`shuf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html):

```sh
arr=( $(shuf -i 1-20 -n 10) )
```

This will print the first 10 of a random arrangement of the numbers 1 through 20, with no duplicates, and store them in a bash array variable `arr`.

If you want to do it in pure bash with no external programs, store the numbers as keys in an associative array and keep generating them until you have 10 elements (Which will all be unique), and use the keys as your normal array elements:

```sh
declare -A nums
while [[ ${#nums[@]} -ne 10 ]]; do nums[$((RANDOM % 20 + 1))]=1; done
arr=( "${!nums[@]}" )
```

Comment: This is even shorter than my suggestion. +1

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use the RANDOM variable

```sh
nums=()
for i in {1..10}; do
    nums+=( $((1 + RANDOM % 100)) )
done
```

Comment: At the time I read the question, there was no constraint on uniqueness.